# jni getMethodID returns Null when used to get ID of constructor

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv, jniwrapper

```
I have assigned jvm to global variable in a function using

int status = (*jenv)->GetJavaVM(jenv, &jvm);
if(status != 0) {
    printf(" Fail!\n");
         }
```

classNameC is a global variable, and its class has no constructor.Then in other function, i am using it like this:

```
JNIEnv *env;
printf("starting function\n");
(*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void **)&env, NULL);
printf("thread attached\n");
jclass local = (*env)->FindClass(env,classNameC);
if(local!=NULL)
{
printf("1st class found\n");
}
jmethodID constructor=(*env)->GetMethodID(env,local,"<init>","()V");
if(constructor==NULL)
{
printf("1st Constructoris NULL\n");
}
else
{
printf("1st Constructor created\n");
}
jobject classObject=(*env)->NewObject(env,local,constructor);
if(classObject==NULL)
{
printf("1st object is  NULL\n");
}
else
{
printf("1st object is  created\n");
}

jclass local1 = (*env)->FindClass(env,"SWIGTYPE_p_void");
if(local1==NULL)
{
printf("SWIGTYPE p void class is NULL\n");
}
else
{
printf("SWIGTYPE p void class created\n");
}
```

This constructor has 2 parametrs one is long and next is boolean. This class has 2 constructors other one has no parameters and initializing members with 0.

```
jmethodID constructor1=(*env)->GetMethodID(env,local1,"<init>","(J;Z;)V");
if(constructor1==NULL)
{
printf("SWIGTYPE p void constructor is NULL\n");
}
else
{
printf("SWIGTYPE p void constructor is created\n");
}
```

when i run it, it successfully printed upto **SWIGTYPE p void class created and SWIGTYPE p void constructor is NULL**  and then it gave this error:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7ec503fa7b, pid=25307,
>   tid=140182441326336
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build
>   1.7.0_65-b17)  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)  Problematic frame:  V 
>   [libjvm.so+0x657a7b] 
>   JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg::JNI_ArgumentPusherVaArg(_jmethodID*,
>   __va_list_tag*)+0x1b
>
> Core dump written. Default location:
>   /home/manish/rathi/libdmc/dmcore/include/core or core.25307
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   /home/manish/rathi/libdmc/dmcore/include/hs_err_pid25307.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: is the jmethodID `constructor` non null?

Comment: yes, i checked it, constructor was null, i used suggestion of Alex in answers,  and got constructor created, but then i got problem with next constructor. This time time I have parameters. I am updating question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find `constructor` method ID; but you claim that this class has no constructor. This means, that `GetMethodID(env,local,"<init>","(V)V")` will return **0**. To specify a signature for a method with no parameters, use `"()V"`.

Comment: Thanks, alex, it worked, and constructor is created, but then on very next line, for next class, i got same problem again. this time   i have constructor in class and this constructor has 2 parameters i.e long and boolean , so i specified J and Z here.

But again got null in constructor.

Comment: Use `(JZ)V"` for signature

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but i wanna know why is it so, i.e. in normal call to getmethodId we put ';' between symbols of different parameters to a function, then why not in case of constructor.

Comment: You only use `;` for "complex" types, e.g. **java.lang.String** -> `Ljava/lang/String;`, but for the primitive types (int, double, etc.) both **L** and semicolon are omitted.